# rule to represent the first full week of the month?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

What iCalendar rrule would represent a date that recurs in for example the first full week of the month, e.g., a club holds a meeting on Friday of the first full week of every month?

Likewise what would the call to create the Google Calendar recurrence rule object look like?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would of course depend on which day is considered for start of the week.

Say it is monday then to have an occurence on the friday of the first full week would be:

RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=FR;BYMONTHDAY=5,6,7,8,9,10,11

Comment: A by month day rule for 7 days from the month day if the first day of the month was the 1st.  Cheers, I'm getting the feeling I'd perhaps rather be programming XSL than RRULEs, but it is kind of clever :)

Comment: Google Calendar apps script API has an 'onlyOnMonthDays' method which would achieve the same thing.